# Convert String which is URL of image to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, image, file, resttemplate

I have an image content coming from Spring RestTemplate `get` result:

```java
String url = "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/" +
        "thumb/Purple114/v4/15/a1/68/15a1681f-dec4-b01f-4362" +
        "-e9ff1ece9c09/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-10-0-0-85" +
        "-220-0.png/60x60bb.png";
String imageAsString = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

I know this is not a right way to fetch image by `RestTemplate`. But I should keep it for my old code.

How can I convert this value to right image byte array format?

`imageAsString.getBytes()` -> this is not the same with `restTemplate.getForObject(url, byte[].class);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image `URL`, you can first [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) it into a `BufferedImage` and then [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) it to a `FileOutputStream` as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/" +
            "thumb/Purple114/v4/15/a1/68/15a1681f-dec4-b01f-4362" +
            "-e9ff1ece9c09/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-10-0-0-85" +
            "-220-0.png/60x60bb.png");

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);

    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png",
            new FileOutputStream("resources/bufferedImage.png"));
}
```

Here is the image: `bufferedImage.png`

[image: bufferedImage.png]